# Filter for records that exist as foreign key in multiple table

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have Django models set up like below.

```
class Person:
    first_name
    last_name
    # More_fields

class Service1:
    person(fk=Person)
    # Service1_specific_fields

class Service2:
    person(fk=Person)
    # Service2_specific_fields

class Service3:
    person(fk=Person)
    # Service3_specific_fields

# More_services
```

I'm trying to create an "advanced search" view that will allow users use checkboxes to query the Person model for records that have services matching the checked boxes.

E.g. If checkboxes for services 1, 2, and 3 are checked, results should only be of Persons that have all three services.

Currently it is set up to get all objects from all 3 services and compare them to one another. As expect, this is extremely slow.

What's a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
( Person
  .objects
  .filter( service1__pk__isnull = False )
  .filter( service2__pk__isnull = False )
  . and so on

 )
```

You can use [Q()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to combine just checked  conditions.